# How to stop item from affecting size of parent when hidden?

Tags: qt, qml

When the `rightDeltaText` item is hidden it still seems to be affecting the height of its parent.

How can I make it not affect the height of its parent?

```
Rectangle {
    id: rightSelectionRect
    anchors.top: parent.top
    anchors.left: rightLine.right
    implicitWidth: leftSelectionLayout.implicitWidth + CustomProperties.Margins.medium * 2
    implicitHeight: leftSelectionLayout.implicitHeight + CustomProperties.Margins.small * 2
    color: CustomProperties.Colors.transparentSelectionBackground

    ColumnLayout {
        id: rightSelectionLayout
        spacing: CustomProperties.Margins.small
        anchors.topMargin: CustomProperties.Margins.small
        anchors.bottomMargin: CustomProperties.Margins.small
        anchors.leftMargin: CustomProperties.Margins.medium
        anchors.rightMargin: CustomProperties.Margins.medium
        anchors.fill: parent

        CustomComponents.HeaderText {
            id: rightText
            text: Converter.formatDuration(ui.selectionModel.endUs, Converter.MicroSeconds, Converter.MicroSeconds)
        }

        CustomComponents.HeaderText {
            id: rightdeltaText
            text: "Δ " + Converter.formatDuration(ui.selectionModel.deltaUs, Converter.MicroSeconds, Converter.MicroSeconds)
            visible: ui.selectionModel.startingOnSmallestValueUs
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show the qml of `CustomComponents.HeaderText`

Comment: Layouts do ignore invisible children. Your problem most likely is that you use `leftSelectionLayout` instead of `rightSelectionLayout` in your `implicitHeight` binding.

Comment: That was it, thank you @GrecKo!